# Something horribly wrong with my js code, anyone can help me debug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write this tool, to animate a game map from a range of dates. The flow is like this:
**1st**: choose game world
**2nd**: set map display parameters (date range, map type and animation speed)
**3rd**: the js code grab png file according to the dates and display them one by one according to the animation speed

The problem I'm having is this:
if you just click on one world, and click animate, everything is fine, the animation displays correctly. Then if you choose another world (without refreshing the page), the animation either flickers or somehow displaying image from other worlds. and I can't figure out what's causing this (I'm totally n00b at js)

```
$(function(){
        $("#image_area").hide();
        $("#tw_image").hide();  
        $('#W40').click(function(){ 
            $("#tw_image").hide();          
            show_image_area('40');
        });

        $('#W42').click(function(){ 
            $("#tw_image").hide();      
            show_image_area('42');
        });

        $('#W56').click(function(){
            $("#tw_image").hide();      
            show_image_area('56');
        });     
    });

    function show_image_area(world){
        $("#tw_image").hide();      
        if(world == "40" || world == "42" || world == "56"){
            $("#map_notice").remove();
            $("#image_area").prepend('<div id="map_notice">Map for W'+world+' available from <span id="date_highlight">April 7th 2011</span>, all previous dates invalid and will not have map available</div>');
        }
        $("#date_from").datepicker({ showAnim: 'blind' });
        $("#date_to").datepicker({ showAnim: 'blind' });
        $('#image_area').show();        
        $("#animate").click(function(){
            $("#tw_image").hide();                                  
            var date_from = $("#date_from").val();
            var date_to = $("#date_to").val();
            if(!(date_from && date_to)){
                alert("From and To dates required.")
                return false;
            }
            var map_type = $("#map_type").val();
            var speed = $("#speed").val();
            var days = daydiff(parseDate(date_from), parseDate(date_to));
            var date_one = new Date(Date.parse(date_from));
            var b = date_one.toISOString().split("T")[0].split("-");
            var c = get_map_type(map_type) + b[0] + b[1] + b[2];
            var width = get_map_type_width(map_type);
            var img_load = "" + world + "/" + c + ".png";
            $('#image_area').load(img_load, function(){
                $("#tw_image").attr("width", width);
                $("#tw_image").attr("src", img_load);
                $("#tw_image").show();
                $("#debug").html("world = "+world);
            });

            var i = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(
            function(){
                date_one.setDate(date_one.getDate() + 1);               
                b = date_one.toISOString().split("T")[0].split("-");
                c = get_map_type(map_type) + b[0] + b[1] + b[2];                    
                var src_one = "" + world + "/"+c+".png";
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = src_one;
                img.onload = function(){
                    $("#tw_image").attr("src", img.src);
                    $("#debug").html("world = "+world);                             
                }
                i++;
                if(i >= days) clearInterval(interval);                              
            },speed);

        });
    }

    function get_map_type(map_type){
        if(map_type == "topk"){
            return "topktribes";
        }
        if(map_type == "toptribe"){
            return "toptribes";
        }
        if(map_type == "topnoble"){
            return "topnoblers";
        }
    }

    function get_map_type_width(map_type){
        if(map_type == "topk"){
            return 1000;
        }
        if(map_type == "toptribe"){
            return 1300;
        }
        if(map_type == "topnoble"){
            return 1300;
        }
    }


    function parseDate(str) {
        var mdy = str.split('/');
        return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
        return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24)
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using Firebug to troubleshoot? See what is happening, or errors that are thrown...

Comment: I did, all I can figure out is that each time it's loading a lot of other world's images, but I still can't figure out what's causing it

Comment: Are you preloading all your images?

Comment: I believe I am in the code, though since I'm n00b at js, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I would say your interval is still looping even after you've changed the map although at the moment I'm still working out how to fix it.

Comment: Thx Nicky, the interval would surely clear after animation is complete right? but still the same thing would happen.

Comment: My other guess after looking at it for a while was that since load is asynchronous it is dropping down to the interval before it has set the new img source.  Unfortunately I was having problems with firebug so I stopped.  Maybe try moving the interval code to the load success function and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Nicky, you gave me something to think about anyway. So how does one's question get more noticed on this site? I'm pretty new

Comment: You can award a bounty to your question after a while http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties aside from that I am not to sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I have a solution here although its not what I thought it was going to be.  Basically every time you are calling image_area_world you are creating a *new* click handler on the animate button.  Due to the way JavaScript scope works the World variable is kept the same for that click handler at the point of creation.

Anyway to solve this problem what you can try is this just before you define your click handler.

```
$("#animate").unbind("click");
$("#animate").click(function () { *code* }
```

A couple of tools to help you out.

1. [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)
2. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Also a bit explaining how [JavaScript Scope and Closures](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) work

Comment: ohhh perfect! Thanks Nicky for taking the time to help me with this issue.